# python: using remove() to remove an element from list by value

Tags: python, list

I wrote a simple script as follows:

```
def  simplefunc(listofcolumns):
    mylist = listofcolumns  
    mylist.remove(1)

listofcolumns = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
simplefunc(listofcolumns)
print listofcolumns
```

The output I get is `[2,3,4,5,6]`. My question is, why is it not `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`? How can I do this

such that I get the answer `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`?

Comment: Just don't do **remove**? Or are you puzzled why lists are called by reference?

Comment: it removes the 1 from your list.

Comment: If you called `my list.remove(1)`, why *wouldn't* you expect `1` to be removed?

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear. I do not want 'listofcolumns' to change. I only want to remove items from 'mylist' and use it inside 'simplefunc'.

Comment: Then you have to make a copy of it first before modifying it, because you are passing your list by reference

Comment: Suppose I hand my kids a box of cookies. When they remove some of the cookies the box now has fewer of them. You handed the list to a function and it took some of the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write mylist = listofcolumns, you aren't making a new list. You're just pointing the variable mylist at the same list that listofcolumns refers to. So any modification you make to mylist or listofcolumns is modifying that same original list. If you want to make a copy of a list so that you can modify it without messing with the original list, you can use the .copy() method, like so:

```
def  simplefunc(listofcolumns):
    mylist = listofcolumns.copy()  
    mylist.remove(1)
```

Or you can do like Kasra suggested and not pass the original list in the first place.

As was pointed out in the comments below, `.copy()` is new to Python 3. For older versions of Python, you can accomplish the same thing by making a slice of the whole list:
    def simplefunc(listofcolumns):
        mylist = listofcolumns[:]
        mylist.remove(1)

Comment: Thanks Erik! I am new to python and this helps. I was doing the exact same thing with integers instead of lists, and the issue didn't arise there.

Comment: mylist = listofcolumns.copy() in .copy() is not support in python2.7  So your answer must be generalized.

Comment: Good point, Sakib. `.copy()` only exists in Python 3, but you can accomplish the same thing in earlier versions by using a slice of the whole list `[:]`.

Comment: Well, you aren't doing _exactly_ the same thing with integers because there are no functions or methods for integers that _modify_ integers (because integers are _immutable_ in Python). A command like `x+=1` doesn't actually change the integer, it just takes a variable that was pointing to one integer and _reassigns_ it to point at an integer that is one bigger. Similarly, if you'd written something like `listofcolumns = listofcolumns[1:]`, you'd be changing which list the local variable `listofcolumns` points to, but the original list would remain unaltered.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of that changing a mutable object argument in a function may impact the caller! and will change your object globally! for get ride of such behavior you can do one of the following ways :

1. pass a copy of your list to function
2. convert your mutable object to an immutable object and then pass.

So you can do :

```
listofcolumns = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
simplefunc(listofcolumns[:])
```

or you can convert your list to a tuple that is a immutable objectbut in your case as `tuple` object has no attribute `remove` you cant use the following way for your problem.:

```
listofcolumns = [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
simplefunc(tuple(listofcolumns))
```

Comment: Great answer, but the problem with #2 is that `remove(1)` wouldn't work unless the function turned it into a mutable object again.

Answer (score 0):

You passing this List by reference. when `mylist = listofcolumns`, all element address are copy in mylist. so when you change in mylist, it also change listofcolumns. But when you use `mylist = listofcolumns[:]` it's only copy elements.
You can try this:

```
def  simplefunc(listofcolumns):
    mylist = listofcolumns[:] 
    mylist.remove(1)
    print listofcolumns
    print mylist

listofcolumns = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
simplefunc(listofcolumns)
print listofcolumns
```